# Redux-Form Dynamically create N forms

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

We are dealing with a case where I need to build *N* forms depending on data fetched from the backend.

All the forms are identical, except for their initial values.

The main problem I'm facing is that I need to plug the reducer to the form using the form name - for instance the following example shows how we are currently plugging the reducer with the form using form name `SHIPPING_ADDRESS_FORM_NAME`:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
const addressReducerPlugin = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE:
            return action.meta.field !== 'country'
                ? state
                : { ...state, values: { ...state.values, state: '' } };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export default formReducer.plugin({
    [SHIPPING_ADDRESS_FORM_NAME]: addressReducerPlugin,
});
```

Is there a way to *dynamically* create *N* separate forms, or do I need to create just 1 form which wraps my *N* forms and indexes them?

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want separate, independent forms for all your shipping addresses (as opposed to one that manages [an array of addresses](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/fieldarrays/), you could just pass a unique name to `reduxForm()` when you decorate them.

```
reduxForm({
  form: 'shippingAddress0'
})(AddressForm)
```

is totally valid.

Does that help?

Comment: I will look into 'field arrays' example. From first look, I probably can solve my case using this pattern. Thanks Erik :)